# how do i make a separate screen for a welcome page in my android app?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an app that will load the user's previous settings and get them on the screen. But to save those settings, I need a page where he'll enter them. So am I supposed to have 2 different classes for these two pages? Or two layouts would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two layouts will work , No need to create extra class.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, You need to create one layout for 'Displaying settings' which would be the main_lauout that would appear on app launch, then to enter the user settings, you have to create another activity which would inflate a new layout 'Enter Settings'. This can be done in several ways, but using a separate activity would be easy to managed in the future as your code grows.